# Scala Convert [Seq[string] to [String]? (TF-IDF after lemmatization)

Tags: scala, tf-idf, lemmatization, lsa

I try to learn scala and specificaly text minning (lemmatization ,TF-IDF matrix and LSA).

I have some texts i want to lemmatize and make a classification (LSA). I use spark on cloudera.

So i used the stanfordCore NLP fonction:

```
    def plainTextToLemmas(text: String, stopWords: Set[String]): Seq[String] = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma")
    val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
    val doc = new Annotation(text)
    pipeline.annotate(doc)
    val lemmas = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
    val sentences = doc.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation])
    for (sentence <- sentences; token <-sentence.get(classOf[TokensAnnotation])) {
    val lemma = token.get(classOf[LemmaAnnotation])
    if (lemma.length > 2 && !stopWords.contains(lemma)) {
    lemmas += lemma.toLowerCase
    }
    }
    lemmas
    }
```

After that, i try to make an TF-IDF matrix but here is my problem:
The Stanford fonction make an RDD in [Seq[string] form.
But, i have an error.
I need to use a RDD in [String] form (not the [Seq[string]] form).

```
val (termDocMatrix, termIds, docIds, idfs) = termDocumentMatrix(lemmatized-text, stopWords, numTerms, sc)
```

Someone know how convert a [Seq[string]] to [String]?

Or i need to change one of my request?.

Thanks for the help.
Sorry if it's a dumb question and for the english.

Bye

Comment: Sorry i need to clarify my question. The lemmatization fonction made a RDD in [Seq[String form]] but i just need a [String form] for the tf-idf. Do you know a lemmatization fonction making a [String] form

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what this lemmatization thingy is, but as far as making a string out of a sequence, you can just do `seq.mkString("\n")` (or replace "\n" with whatever other separator you want), or just `seq.mkString` if you want it merged without any separator.

Also, don't use mutable structures, it's bad taste in scala:

```
val lemmas = sentences
  .map(_.get(classOf[TokensAnnotation]))
  .map(_.get(classOf[LemmaAnnotation]))
  .filter(_.length > 2)
  .filterNot(stopWords)
  .mkString
```